# Need help to link several objects to one another (main object) with some specificities

Tags: json, jq

Need help to link several objects to one another (main object) with some specificities.

Hello, I need help to make this rendering from a JSON file.
I tried several filters, I never managed to make it work the way I wanted.
(This is a simplified example of my JSON file)

Input JSON:

```
[  
  {
    "id": "AAKG",
    "data": "some data...",
    "main_id": "none"
  },
  {
    "id": "PMBL",
    "data": "some data...",
    "main_id": "none"
  },
  {
    "id": "ZDFG",
    "data": "some data...",
    "main_id": "PMBL"
  },
  {
    "id": "XHGF",
    "data": "some data...",
    "main_id": "PMBL"
  },
  {
    "id": "LOKJ",
    "data": "some data...",
    "main_id": "none"
  },
  {
    "id": "JQWC",
    "data": "some data...",
    "main_id": "none"
  },
  {
    "id": "QQSZ",
    "data": "some data...",
    "main_id": "none"
  },
  {
    "id": "JQWC",
    "data": "some data...",
    "main_id": "QQSZ"
  },
  {
    "id": "LLRE",
    "data": "some data...",
    "main_id": "none"
  }
]
```

Output (what i want):

```
[  
  {
    "id": "AAKG",
    "data": "some data...",
    "main_id": "none"
  },
  {
    "id": "PMBL",
    "data": "some data...",
    "main_id": "none"
    "details": [
            {
                "id": "ZDFG",
                "data": "some data...",
                "main_id": "PMBL"
            },
            {
                "id": "XHGF",
                "data": "some data...",
                "main_id": "PMBL"
            }
        ]
  },
  {
    "id": "LOKJ",
    "data": "some data...",
    "main_id": "none"
  },
  {
    "id": "JQWC",
    "data": "some data...",
    "main_id": "none"
  },
  {
    "id": "QQSZ",
    "data": "some data...",
    "main_id": "none"
    "details": [
            {
                "id": "JQWC",
                "data": "some data...",
                "main_id": "QQSZ"
            }
        ]
  },
  {

  },
  {
    "id": "LLRE",
    "data": "some data...",
    "main_id": "none"
  }
]
```

Explanations:

In my input I have only one array that covers all the objects in my file, I would like to link all the objects in an Array that have in the "main_id" key value a specific value other than "none" (with key "details"), to the object (which I call the parent object) containing that same value in the "id" key of the parent object.

As you can see in my output example, which I think is more explicit than my explanations.
Of course my real input file contains many more objects
but the structure remains the same as in my example.
[object,object,object,....]

Answer (score 1):

A simple `reduce` with an `if` expression builig up an indexed object may suffice. The final `map` converts the object back to an array.

```bash
reduce .[] as $i ({};
  if $i.main_id == "none" then .[$i.id] += $i
  else .[$i.main_id].details += [$i] end
) | map(.)
```

```json
[
  {
    "id": "AAKG",
    "data": "some data...",
    "main_id": "none"
  },
  {
    "id": "PMBL",
    "data": "some data...",
    "main_id": "none",
    "details": [
      {
        "id": "ZDFG",
        "data": "some data...",
        "main_id": "PMBL"
      },
      {
        "id": "XHGF",
        "data": "some data...",
        "main_id": "PMBL"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "LOKJ",
    "data": "some data...",
    "main_id": "none"
  },
  {
    "id": "JQWC",
    "data": "some data...",
    "main_id": "none"
  },
  {
    "id": "QQSZ",
    "data": "some data...",
    "main_id": "none",
    "details": [
      {
        "id": "JQWC",
        "data": "some data...",
        "main_id": "QQSZ"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "LLRE",
    "data": "some data...",
    "main_id": "none"
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/B-017OhagKv)

Comment: Thank you very much that worked, however how can I get rid of the key "main_id", I tried ..... | map(. | del(.details[0].main_id)) but it removed that the "main_id" of the first object of "details", I found a solution not at all practical because I do not know how many object I can expect: ..... | map(. | del(.details[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7....].main_id)) and when I test with the [] (without anything) it gives me an error.

Comment: @PearlLea Change `+= $i` to `+= ($i | del(.main_id))`, and `+= [$i]` to `+= [$i | del(.main_id)]` (both delete the field in their respective branches) [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/qxDDTInt6QV)